# Click on link in ajax not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my ajax and html code. When I click on Recipient Country on link, it is unable to loaded the recipient_country.html, which I called on GET method below.

```
<div id = "topbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#recipient_country.html" onclick = "recipient_country()">Recipient Country</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id = "content"></div>

function recipient_country(e) {

    (e || window.event).preventDefault();

    var con = document.getElementById('content'), xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) { 

        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            con.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }

    xhr.open("GET", "recipient_country.html", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: this is an old ajax method. Please use jquery ajax it is simplest and easy to code

Comment: @Sudharsan: jQuery is not the answer to every javascript question...

Comment: @karlipoppins - I am not said like that jquery is easy to learn and code quickly

Comment: @karlipoppins - Yes, aspirin answerd in query method you compare what is the best way jquery or javascript.

Comment: Well he has a jQuery tag soo... XD

Comment: @Sudharsan Let them go, if they support using inline event handlers..

Comment: @Sudharsan: i'm not trying to start a war, i'm just saying that it's important to understand how things work before saying "jQuery!!", especially when the question contains no jQuery. You're stating that he is using an "old ajax method" by manipulating an XMLHttpRequest object directly... But what do you think jQuery's `ajax()` method really does? If you look at its source, you'll see that it's just a wrapper for that same `XMLHttpRequest` object the question is mentionning.

Comment: @karlipoppins - If the OP really want the answer only in javascript he didn't tag the jquery in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass the parameter `event` to the calling method. Because of the paramter mismatch, `recipient_country(e)` method never be called. Pass the `event` to the function at the time of click.

```
 <li><a href="#recipient_country.html" onclick = "recipient_country(event)">Recipient Country</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've also tagged jQuery, might I suggest making use of the its [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method

```
function recipient_country()
{
    $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url:'recipient_country.html',
      success:function(response)
      {
          $('#content').html(response);
      }
   });
   return false;
}
```

If you plan to use jQuery version > 1.8, you will need to slightly change your code as

```
function recipient_country()
 {   
    $.ajax({
       url: "test.html",
       type:"get",   
    }).done(function(response) {
          $('#content').html(response);
    });
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> is this valid jquery library?

Comment: I have got this error when clicking on that link Ignoring get or set of property that has [LenientThis] because the "this" object is incorrect. reps.js:494
The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.

Comment: ReferenceError: google is not defined shown in firebug